# How to convert json to Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have to convert the JSON string to Dictionary< string, object >. For that, I am following something here https://www.programming-books.io/essential/csharp/collect-all-fields-of-json-object-5293c4c9342c403bb40dd9232692a7bc and doing DotNotation to convert it to Dictionary however, the output is not as expected.

JSON Data I am trying:

```
{
  "name": "Madame Uppercut",
  "age": 39,
  "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
  "powers": [
    "Million tonne punch",
    "Damage resistance",
    "Superhuman reflexes"
  ],
  "accounting": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 23
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Mary",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "age": 32
    }
  ]
}
```

Using the code from above link and converting from DotNotation as below

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var jsonInput in dotNotation)
            {
                var hierarchy = jsonInput.Key.Split('.');

                var bottom = dictionary;

                for (int i = 0; i < hierarchy.Length; i++)
                {
                    var key = hierarchy[i];

                    if (i == hierarchy.Length - 1)
                    {
                        bottom.Add(key, jsonInput.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!bottom.ContainsKey(key))
                            bottom.Add(key, new Dictionary<string, object>());

                        bottom = (Dictionary<string, object>)bottom[key];
                    }
                }
            }
```

finally, the result is like.

[image]

Now, what I want is to group the arrays(powers and accounting). I know the JToken path is giving '[]' array path but I want it like below for power and account in the dictionary.

```
{[power, [{"Million tonne punch" }, {"Damage resistance" }, {"Superhuman reflexes"}]]}
```

Comment: IIRC, do notation is used to get a flattened json string. If you need a dictionary, why just don't deserialize a json into `Dictionary<string, object>` directly? Is json structure the same all the time?

Comment: Yes. I am doing this for something else however if I deserialize `Dictionary<string, object>` still it will not be grouped by default. Json will not be same it can be more complex structure too.

Comment: So, you want to have an array as single object under the key in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes please and some generic code which can fit into more complex type like array inside array too.

Comment: Well, why you don't use the code from link, mentioned in your question? Your actual code is different from that code, which allows to parse any complex json and join array into single string after small modification

Comment: The code from the link gives with dotnotation something like main.child[0].innerchild[0].property. Code on this question is to convert the Dot Notation to Dictionary but it is capable of doing with array not grouping the Dotnotation to single key and value.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Comment: I have to loop through each key and value to find the type and some operations and have to do to set custom values on conditional. So, just deserializing won't solve my request.